# Compiler errors due to missing variables (the variable is defined in a different class)

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, scope

I'm a beginner to java programming, and was trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors game.
I apologize for the lack of comments.

This is my main program, it calls on the other two objects.

```
 import java.util.*;

  public class RPSMain extends RPSPlayer{
   RPSPlayer player = new RPSPlayer();
   RPSGame gameObject = new RPSGame ();
   public void main () {


     Random generator = new Random ();
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print ("Number of Rounds: ");
     int rounds = sc.nextInt();


    //Call and process all of the methods found in RPSPlayer and RPSGame
     for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++){
        player.makeThrow();
        gameObject.makeThrow();
        gameObject.announceWinner (compThrow, getPThrow);
     }
    //Final Output
     System.out.print (gameObject.bigWinner(winner, rounds));
  }
//accessor to return round to RPSGame
   public static int getRound (int round){
     this.round = round;
     return round;
  }
}
```

My first object is where the player inputs the number of throws that they would like, and it is processed there.

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class RPSPlayer {

  public static void main (String args[]) {
     Random generator = new Random ();
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  }
//This method gets the throw, and loops if throw is not within 1 and 3
  public static int makeThrow (){
     Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
     int playerThrow;
     do{
        System.out.print ("Enter your throw (1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors)");
        playerThrow = sc.nextInt();
     } while (playerThrow > 3 && playerThrow < 1);
     return playerThrow;
  }

    //Accessor method
  public static int getThrow (int playerThrow){
    this.playerThrow = playerThrow;
     return playerThrow;
  }


 }
```

The last object is where all of the calculations happen.
There is a lot of variables that don't compile properly, and I can't quite figure out why...

```
  import java.util.*;

 public class RPSGame extends RPSPlayer{
  RPSPlayer player = new RPSPlayer();
  RPSGame game = new RPSGame ();
  RPSMain mainRPS = new mainRPS();
   public static void main (String args[]) {

     Random generator = new Random ();
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int rounds = mainRPS.getRound(rounds);
   }
   //Random Throw Generator
   public static int makeCompThrow (){
     int Max = 3;
     int Min = 1;

     int compThrow =   Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
     return compThrow;
  }

   //  Get the throw from the player in RPSPlayer
       public static int getPlayerThrow (){
     RPSPlayer player = new RPSPlayer();
     int getPThrow = player.makeThrow();
     return getPThrow;
  }

 //Does all of the calculatoins and ouputs who threw what.
   public static int announceWinner (int compThrow, int getPThrow) {
     int winner = 0;

     if (getPThrow == 1){
        System.out.println ("Player throws ROCK.");
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 2){
        System.out.println ("Player throws PAPER.");
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 3){
        System.out.println ("Player throws SCISSORS.");
     }


     if (compThrow == 1){
        System.out.println ("Computer throws ROCK.");
     }
     else if (compThrow == 2){
        System.out.println ("Computer throws PAPER.");
     }
     else if (compThrow == 3){
        System.out.println ("Computer throws SCISSORS.");
     }

     if (getPThrow == compThrow){
        winner = 3;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 1 && compThrow == 3){
        winner = 1;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 1 && compThrow == 2){
        winner = 2;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 2 && compThrow == 1){
        winner = 1;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 2 && compThrow == 3){
        winner = 2;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 3 && compThrow == 1){
        winner = 2;
     }
     else if (getPThrow == 3 && compThrow == 2){
        winner = 1;
     }  

     return winner;
   }

//Final Output with imported values of 'rounds' and 'winner'
   public int bigWinner (int winner, int rounds){
     int tie = 0;
     int playerWins = 0;
     int compWins = 0;

     if (winner == 1){
        playerWins = playerWins + 1;
     }

     else if (winner == 0){
        tie = tie + 1;
     }

     else if (winner == 3){
        compWins = compWins + 1;
     }
     System.out.println ("You win " +playerWins+ ". Computer wins " +(compWins)+ ".");
     if (playerWins > compWins){
        System.out.print ("You win!"); 
     }
     if (playerWins < compWins){
        System.out.print ("Computer wins!"); 
     }

     if (playerWins == compWins){
        System.out.print ("It's a tie!"); 
     }
     return tie;
  }


 }
```

When compiled again, 2 new errors appear after adding in WATTO Studios' suggestions, these are the compiler errors:

```
RPSMain.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable winner
location: class RPSMain
     RPSGame.bigWinner(winner, rounds);
                       ^
RPSMain.java:23: non-static method bigWinner(int,int) cannot be referenced 
from a static context
     RPSGame.bigWinner(winner, rounds);
```

Why can't it find the variable 'winner' if I'm referencing from RPSGame, and why is it still searching RPSMain for the variable?

Comment: Could you please post the first error message you get. You **always** fix the first error first, as it can often create errors later on.

Comment: "There is a lot of variables that don't compile properly, and I can't quite figure out why." What are the compilation errors?

Comment: `RPSMain mainRPS = new mainRPS();` should probably be `RPSMain mainRPS = new RPSMain();`

Comment: I have added some more information to my answer that will help you understand a little more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these errors, in your `RPSMain` class, you're trying to access variables from your other classes. Your code here...

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++){
    player.makeThrow();
    gameObject.makeThrow();
    gameObject.announceWinner (compThrow, getPThrow);
 }
```

Should actually be this...

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++){
    int playerThrow = player.makeThrow();
    int compThrow = gameObject.makeCompThrow();
    gameObject.announceWinner (compThrow, playerThrow );
 }
```

Note that when we call a method like `makeThrow()`, we capture the variable and call it `playerThrow`. Now we can use this variable in the `announceWinner()` method. The same for the `compThrow` variable.

You are doing the same thing in your `RPSGame.bigWinner(winner, rounds);` line - its complaining that `winner` doesn't exist. This is true - `winner` is not a variable in `RPSMain`, its only a variable in `RPSGame` - you can't share the variables between different classes like this.

Your `gameObject.announceWinner()` method returns an `int` that represents the actual winner. If you want to use this returned value, you need to capture it into a variable. Currently you have code like this in `RPGMain`...

```
for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++){
   int playerThrow = player.makeThrow();
   int compThrow = gameObject.makeCompThrow();
   gameObject.announceWinner (compThrow, playerThrow );
}
System.out.print (gameObject.bigWinner(winner, rounds));
```

If you want to keep the `int` returned from the `announceWinner()` method, you have to capture it by making the following adjustment...

```
for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++){
   int playerThrow = player.makeThrow();
   int compThrow = gameObject.makeCompThrow();
   int winner = gameObject.announceWinner (compThrow, playerThrow );
   System.out.print (gameObject.bigWinner(winner, rounds));
}
```

This now says that the value returned from `gameObject.announceWinner()` will be stored in a local variable called `winner` in the `RPGMain` class. Now When it tries to use the `winner` variable in the `gameObject.bigWinner()` method of the next line, it knows about the value.

To fix your `non-static method bigWinner(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context` error, you need to change the following line...

```
public int bigWinner (int winner, int rounds){
```

to have the word `static` in it, like this...

```
public static int bigWinner (int winner, int rounds){
```

Or, better yet, remove the word `static` from everywhere in your code. If you're new to Java, trying to use `static` variables and methods will just make things more complicated then they really need to be, and I can't see any reason why you'd need them to be `static` in your program.

Comment: @kryyn: recompile after making these changes and repost any errors you encounter!!

Answer (score 1):

`compThrow` and `getPThrow` are local variables of `RPSGame`. You cant use them in `RPSMain`.
One way to use them would be to send these to `RPSMain` via a method call as arguments and redeclare variables in `RPSMain` to accept these.

Other and more preferable solution would be to make them protected instance variables in class `RPSPlayer`. That way they will be available to both `RPSGame` and `RPSMain` via inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Mental note:  it seems like you've got a large # of static methods, and some classes that are composed entirely of static methods, yet you still instantiate the class and call the methods as if they are part of the object instance.

In general, when calling a static method, you should use a static reference:

```
RSPGame.makeCompThrow();
```

instead of this

```
RSPGame game = new RSPGame().
game.makeCompThrow();
```

which should generate compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I'll  nitpick your `makeThrow` method:

```
} while (playerThrow > 3 && playerThrow < 1);
```

that will never loop, because no number is smaller than 1 AND (`&&`) bigger than 3.
It should read

```
} while (playerThrow > 3 || playerThrow < 1);
```

Bigger than 3 OR (`||`) smaller than 1. Now it should work as intended.